# Using Amazon S3 php REST API vs. Mounting S3 bucket to server (s3fs)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, s3fs

I will be launching an application in the very near future which will, in part, require users to upload files (images) to be viewed by other members. I like the idea of S3 as it is relatively cheap and scales automatically.

My problem is how I will have users upload their images to S3. It seems there are a few options.

1-  Use the php REST API.  The only problem is that I can't get it to work for uploading variously scaled versions (ie thumbnails) of the same image simultaneously and uploading them directly to s3 (it works for just one image at a time this way).  Overall, it just seems less flexible.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/

2-  The other option would be to mount an S3 bucket with s3fs.  Then just programmatically move my images into the bucket like I would with NFS.  From what I've read, it seems some people are dubious of the reliability of mounting S3.  Is this true?

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=fuse+over+amazon

Which method would be better for maximum reliability and speed?

Would EBS be something to consider?  I would really like to have a dedicated box rather than use an EC2 instance, though...

Comment: Hi minjoon, EBS is not something to consider if you want to scale. Consider EBS as a pendrive, you can attach to a single host, EBS don't work as NAS or S3.

Comment: Did you found the best solution minjoon? I'm in the Middle of the same decision of what is a better solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For your use case I recommend to use the S3 API directly rather than using s3fs because of performance. Remember that s3fs is just another layer on top of S3's API and it's usage of that API is not always the best one for your application.

To handle the creation of thumbnails, I recommend to decouple that from the main upload process by using Amazon Simple Queue Service. That way your users will receive a response as soon as a file is uploaded without having to wait for it to be processed resulting in shorter response times.

As for using EBS, that is a different scenario. EBS is just a persistent storage for and Amazon EC2 instance and it's reliability doesn't compare with S3.

It's also important to remember that S3 only offers "eventual consistency" as opposed to a physical HDD on your machine or an EBS instance on EC2 so you need to code your app to handle that correctly.

Comment: I dont think s3fs can be used in production.